# How to position a pop up to be in the top right part of the screen

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, resize, window

What I want to do is to change the size of a window and create a window next to it so they are exactly next to each other. In that sense, I need to position to the new window to the top right part of the screen, the way I am doing it is not working (code is below), I need help :)

```
function () { 
   var viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   var viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   window.resizeBy(-300,0); 
   window.open("something.htm",
     "mywindow",
     "width=300,
     height=viewportheight,
     left=(viewportwidth - 300),
     top=0,
     screenX=0,
     screenY=0"); 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
window.resizeBy(-300,0);
window.moveTo(0,0);

window.open("http://google.com",
            "mywindow",
            "width=300,left="+(viewportwidth-300)+",top=0");
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested out the actual window size math; not sure if that's correct.  But the first, obvious, problem you have is embedding the variables into the call to window.open.  Try changing

```
  window.open("something.htm", "mywindow",
 "width=300, height=viewportheight, left=(viewportwidth - 300), top=0, screenX=0, screenY=0");
```

to

```
  window.open("something.htm", "mywindow",
 "width=300, height=" + viewportheight + ", left=" + (viewportwidth - 300) + ", top=0, screenX=0, screenY=0");
```

Basically, if you want the variables or the math to get resolved, they have to be outside the string.